# Mass distribution inside inner horizon of a charged black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reissner-nordstrom-metric

I am trying to understand the spatial geometry inside the inner horizon of a charged black hole. I assume the charge accumulates exactly on the inner horizon (https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/bh/rn.html).
What about the mass distribution of the rest, non-charged matter? Does it spread uniformly inside the inner horizon, or does it collapse into singularity?

Comment: Once you're inside the event horizon, everything goes to the singularity.

Comment: @zeta-band - not in a charged black hole, in that case you can never hit the singularity, see page 256 (pdf 274), paragraph 10.13 in this reference: https://tinyurl.com/y84g6vbv

Answer (score 1):

> I assume the charge accumulates exactly on the inner horizon

The standard black hole solutions are vacuum solutions, so there is zero charge density and zero mass density at all points in the spacetime.

Real-world black hole solutions form by gravitational collapse, so they're not vacuum solutions, but the mass and charge density at a particular point in such a spacetime is an accident of its formation.

Comment: In my question I meant the distribution of matter inside inner horizon of real-world black holes long time after collapse.

Comment: Reissner–Nordstrom, which applies to a charged black hole, is not a vacuum solution.  I would consider that to be a "standard black hole solution" and somewhat applicable to the question.